# Rails emits warning: "Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've recently upgraded my Rails to v3.2.  The server starts and works, however I'm noticing the following warning:

```
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
```

In my development.rb I have the following configuration for cache control:

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=36000"
```

What does the warning mean and what should I do to address it?

Comment: You should remove this option and use asset pipeline instead

Comment: Thanks.  I left configuring asset pipeline for the next step, will see shortly if the warning goes away.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The warning is [caused by a call from within Rails itself](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8812). The warning has been fixed in [Rails 3.2.13](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/).

Comment: I don't really understand that link...What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Not a great deal, I'm afraid, until a new release of Rails comes out. In any case, it's a warning rather than an error.

Comment: This should be fixed in Rails 3.2.13 which just went into beta - so soon!

Comment: But is there a Rack config to silence warnings?

Comment: FYI, latest Rails is v 3.2.21, I set it in the Gemfile, and the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade Rake file. This issue occurred in *Rails 3.2.12* but solved in **Rails 3.2.13** to solve this issue. You have to delete your `Gemfile.lock` from your app (NOTE:  As you may get error something like "Rakefile locked", Take backup of Gemfile.lock file if this solution won't help).

Open your Gemfile and find `gem 'rails', '3.2.12'` and replace it with **`gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`** then in your terminal run `bundle install`. Now you will not get this warning.